# Why is Elasticsearch not counting new documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I just added a bunch of documents to my elasticsearch index but when I run a count query I see that the count hasn't changed. I've queried the index and seen that the new documents have been added. Here's the query:

`GET /listings/_count?q=type:long`

What do I need to do to get the right count?

Answer (score 0):

can you just remove the filter which you adding, and try with simple `GET /listings/_count` API, and see if it returns the total no of documents in your index.

I am guessing there is something wrong with your condition `q=type:long`, and in order to debug that you need to provide your index mapping and sample documents which you are indexing and expect them to come in your this filtered query of count API.